# How to define an object for function to return

Tags: kotlin

I am trying this snippet from Hyperskill in Kotlin.
I have tried in an IDE but keep getting error because of inproper `Product` reference.
How can I create a proper `Product` object to make it run?

```
class Fridge {
        fun open() = println(1)
        fun find(productName: String): Product {
            println(productName)
            return 4
        }
        fun close() = println(3)
    }
```

Comment: You simply need to make a `Product` class and instantiate it for the return value of `find(String)`. Even something basic like `data class Product(val name: String)` might be enough to satisfy this particular situation. At least as far as getting it to compile; getting it to do what you want might take more effort.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are trying to return integer (`return 4`) from method `find(String): Product`, but you are declaring return type of `Product`.

You gave to either return object of a class `Product` or change the method to return `Int` (`fun find(productName: String): Int`).

In order to return an object of class `Product`, the following code is sufficient:

```kotlin
class Product

class Fridge {
    fun open() = println(1)
    fun find(productName: String): Product {
        println(productName)
        return Product()
    }
    fun close() = println(3)
}
```